# Validation Rule with multiple picklist fields

Tags: picklist, validation, validation-rule

I need to create a validation rule that fires where when either "Complete" or "Closed" is chosen from a picklist, another picklist becomes a required field. I have tried multiple options, but have not had luck yet. So far this is what I have tried:

```
AND (
   ISPICKVAL(Status__c, "Complete" || ISPICKVAL (Status__c, "Closed"),
   NOT(ISCHANGED(Root_Cause__c))
)
```

Both Root_Cause__c and Status__c are picklists.

I am currently getting a FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION error on the page. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What is the data type of Root Cause?

Comment: @sfdcfox It is also a picklist

Comment: Leah, please **[edit]** your post with any clarifications. Comments are good for *asking* for clarification, but *providing* it should be done by making the `Question` itself more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Start with your root criterion, namely this other field being null. The approach may vary based on field type, but that might look like:

```
ISBLANK(Root_Cause__c)
```

**EDIT** Now that you have explicated this field to be a picklist, you can change this check to:

```
ISPICKVAL(Root_Cause__c, "")
```

Now layer on top of that your check on the value of `Status`. You can do it the way you have, but please try to always use functions instead of `&&` and `||`, as that will be more consistent with the rest of your formula. So it would be better to do:

```
OR(ISPICKVAL(...), ISPICKVAL(...))
```

Better yet, though, is to use a `CASE` function so that you only reference the field once (field references are expensive):

```
1 = CASE(Status__c, "Complete", 1, "Closed", 1, 0)
```

Now the field you actually want to check if it changed should also be this status field. Putting it all together:

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(Root_Cause__c, ""),
    ISCHANGED(Status__c),
    1 = CASE(
        Status__c,
        "Complete", 1,
        "Closed", 1,
        0
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian. When I check syntax in the formula editor, I am still getting this error message:                             Error: Field Root_Cause__c is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions

Comment: @LeahG Hence why sfdcfox asked you to clarify your question. I have updated my post accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. I am still only a few months into working with Salesforce so I am still learning! I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your page is a visualforce page? if so, you need to use 'try catch' like below code.

```
Account acc = new Account();
acc.Name = 'ABC';
try {
    insert acc;
} catch (DmlException e) {
for (Integer i = 0; i < e.getNumDml(); i++) {
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, e.getDmlMessage(i)));
}
```